# Combine all SSRS reports in the Grid into one report

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, reporting-services

It should be very simple and should employ multi-value parameters , but not able to figure out how ? 
This report **takes parameters** from the **GridView**
 I have a gridview in an asp.net web page which has **print button** for every row to print this report for that row.

Now, there are **as many reports** as there are **rows** in the grid.---[This part is done]

So,how about **combining all these reports** into one single report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a subreport for each one of you reports.
You just create a new report and start inserting subreports in each row.

Check this documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220581.aspx

Here's an example for you:

1 - Create a new report. You can then add a tablix to it, in case you have more info, which is the case in my example. Just don't forget to add a dataset to that tablix if that's your case.

This is how it would look
[image]

Each gray line is a subreport.

2 - To insert a subreport just right-click a cell and go to `Insert > Subreport`

3 - Right-click your subreport, select `Subreport Properties` and choose your report from the drop-down menu:

[image]

[image]

4 - You can then set the parameters your subreport will receive:

[image]

Case 2: if you don't need a tablix for aditional info, just repeat the same process in a `Rectangle`.

---

**UPDATE**

As I said in my comment, here's one report in which I do exactly what you want:

[image]

As you can see the subreports are part of the main report's body that has other data.

I need to repeat these subreports for each record and that's how it is done.

Here you can see the `Id` being passed as parameter to my subreport:

[image]

From what I understood, that's what you want. That way for each record its current `Id` would be passed to the report. Generating a report with that **"dynamic"** parameter you mentioned.

Comment: thnx estein , but the issue is that Grid is dynamic, that is, its data is based on certain filter conditions, so I really do not have the option of adding sub-reports coz there are actually hundreds of rows <br /> it is something like I'm taking a parameter from the grid row and displaying the report. So for every row,I am getting that particular column value and passing that to report as parameter and generating the report, Now here I could have used multi-value parameters, but CANNOT, as using DB2. So am still figuring out

Comment: @Ciphers you can set your subreport to receive the field you want as parameter. Your subreport inside the tablix will be just like a normal report, foreach record in your dataset return it will be called once. You just have to pass the field value you want. I'll update my answer with an image where I'm doing exactly what you want.